# i can't understand these following code

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not understanding how these secure random numbers converted to 1 and automatically rearrange to an array.

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

int [] array = new int[7];

for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
{
    int random = 1+ secureRandom.nextInt(6);
    array[random]=1+array[random];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what your question is.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see exactly what each line of code is doing.

Comment: Are you asking how `array[random]` works?

Comment: No, he is asking why is it possible such a disposition in an array if the origin of the data is a random number generator between 0..6.

Comment: no i'm asking about output, if i use secure random between 1 to 6 number then it'll produce 1,,,6 but in the output it's showing 1 and rapidly add 1 number to it's next time.. but how?

Comment: The java Array is initialised with all 0s. You are just adding 1 to random elements . Some values are therefore even bumped to higher than 1.  Also, what is being printed is 5 different such arrays. BTW, you are not setting the 0th element (adding 1) , so you will find only 0s at the start of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through this code.

We begin by creating an instance of SecureRandom().  According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), this will let us generate

> cryptographically strong random numbers

meaning they will be very random.  Read about [pseudorandom number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) if you would like to know what this avoids.

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
```

Now we will create an array of seven ints, initially set to `0`.

```
int [] array = new int[7];
```

We will run the contents of the for-loop five times.

```
for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
```

The start of the loop gets a random number between 1 and 6, inclusive, and assigns it to `random`.

```
int random = 1+ secureRandom.nextInt(6);
```

We now increment the array at the random position.  Notice how position `0` is never updated, since it's not in the range of possible values for `random`.

At the end of each loop, we print the contents of the array to std-out, which let's us see the loop increment an element each time.  This is also why you see five prints of the entire array.  Arrays.toString converts the array to the comma-separated version you see.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

EDIT:

From what I understand in your comments, you would like to know why the values in the array update by 1 instead of become the random number.

The array is represented by indexes as follows:

```
array: { array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5], array[6] }
```

When we access the array with `array[random]`, we are using `random` as the index.  It will look at the value of random and match it with the same number in `[ ]` above.  Then, since you say `1 + array[random]`, it only changes the value at that position in the array by `1`.

EDIT x2: If you wanted the other output, you would need the contents of the for-loop to be:

```
int random = 1 + secureRandom.nextInt(6);
int anotherRandom = 1 + secureRandom.nextInt(6);
array[random] = anotherRandom;
System.out.print(...);
```

This will set the value of the (almost) random position to a random value within the same range of possible indexes.

Comment: i want to know instead of this [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2] output  why don't this giving me this output [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6]
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6]

Comment: if array length is more than 7 such as 100 then what will happen ? is it counting [ int random = 1+ secureRandom.nextInt(6); ] random length 1 to 6 as it's array length ?

Comment: If you make the length of the array more than 7 without modifying the random number generation in your original code or my EDIT x2 code, only numbers from array[1] through array[6] (inclusive) will become non-zero.  Meaning all of the new positions will remain zero.

Comment: If you wanted all positions to potentially be updated, you would need to generate the random used for the index as int randomNdx = secureRandom.nextInt(array.length - 1).

Comment: Great, and no problem!

Comment: Try to set up an IDE if you don't have one.  It will let you see compilation issues quickly.  You will also be able to see Javadoc information (Google if you can't figure out how) within your development environment, which usually has a short explanation of methods.  I've used Codecademy for intro tutorials before.  I have not completed their Java tutorial, though.  https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java  Experience is the best way to learn and it will come with time!

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious from code that  the value of random numbers aren't written  to array.. value is used as index. If to assume that at first array is zeroed, then first iteration would write 1 + 0 to random array element (excluding 0 element). later it may be  1 + value of random element, which on second iteration will be 1 or 2,  on 3rd - from 1 to 3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the key line:

```
array[random]=1+array[random];
```

some random element became 1+0 first time. When we randomly get it second time - it became 1+1, at third - 1+2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you mix content of array with position in array, the position is found by random and the content is found by the content of a random position +1.
If you want to have content from 0 to 6 inside the arrays you should use

```
array[random] = secureRandom.nextInt(6)
```

instead of

```
array[random]=1+array[random];
```